# this code is not working on tensorflow 2.16.0+ version

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    './base.model',
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True,
    mode='max',
    save_weights_only=False,
    save_frequency=1
)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0.001,
    patience=30,
    verbose=1,
    mode='auto'
)

opt1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

callbacks = [checkpoint,earlystop]
```

this isn't working on tensorflow 2.16.1
but, working on 2.15.0 on google colab

how can i fix my code or how can i install tensorflow 2.15.0 ?

i tried `pip install tensorflow=2.15.0`
but, it's showing error

Comment: "Not working" and "showing error" (without actually showing the error) are no helpful descriptions. What are the actual error messages/full stack traces? Please not as images, but as text in the question.

Comment: this error

'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5a7537451b77> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
      2     './base.model',
      3     monitor='val_accuracy',
      4     verbose=1,
      5     save_best_only=True,

TypeError: ModelCheckpoint.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_frequency'
'''

Answer (score 0):

The error in your comment says `save_frequency` is an unknown keyword for `ModelCheckpoint`. [In the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint#args) it shows that `ModelCheckpoint` expects `save_freq` as an argument. Also beware that if you set an integer for `save_freq`, it saves each x batches, not epochs. If you just want it to save every epoch, you can set

```py
save_freq='epoch'
```

which is also the default.
Why this woked in 2.15, I can not say, the docs for 2.15 also have `save_freq` in it. Maybe it was compatible with `save_frequency` in the background up to that point. It is better to use `save_freq`, as it is officially supported.

If you want to change a package version in colab, use

```
%pip install -U "tensorflow~=2.15.0"
```

`%` enables the pip command outside the python environment, `-U` upgrades (or in your case downgrades) existing versions and you need `""` and  either == or ~= for the version numbers. == for exact this version and ~= for, in this example "2.15.x", where x is the newest version.